# How to detect object property delete

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Hey in my component template I iterate over object property. 
The problem is when I delete one of them the template doesn't refresh.
How can I refresh them? 
Object looks loke this:

```
{name:'david', year:12, parents:{mother:MotherObject,father:FatherObject}}
```

And an object like this I delete in parents mother but the template doesn't refresh.
I use `delete [propertyname]` to delete property.

I tried zone.run() but nothing changes. Can anyone knows how can I force refresh template?

Comment: Have you tried using the `ChangeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` ?

Comment: add  this.ref.detectChanges(); after changing and its not working. In log i see i change but not in template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess you are using *Pipe*(if not, let me know) to iterate over object properties, the reason is that angular triggers object `instance` for DetectChange, and  deleting properties of object won't change the original instance and this is why DetectChange won't fire.

you have to create a new instance when you delete some fields, here is one way using ES6 new feature:

```
obj = {...obj};  // copy obj with a new instance
```

Add another way using `Object.assign`

```
obj = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/slsspbyhkTYkPxDx1sEa?p=preview)**

Comment: You know how to o this in es5 ./?